# Rsync failed: Permission denied (13) ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsync

I am trying to setup rsync to backup to a remote ssh server but I get this error:

```
rsync: opendir "/home/backup/." failed: Permission denied (13)
```

this is the rsync command:

```
sudo -u admin rsync -avzh /home/backup/ sam@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/sam/prodweb
```

I am trying to run the command as the admin user, since he has permissions to the tar files inside the backup folder.
This is the setup where the folders live:

```
sudo ls -l /home/
total 4
drwx--x--x. 9 admin  admin   172 Mar 19 12:49 admin
drwx--x--x. 3 backup backup 4096 Apr  8 03:10 backup
drwx------. 6 sam sam  228 Apr  3 15:08 sam
sudo ls -l /home/backup/
total 12902820
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  214722560 Apr  6 03:10 admin.2020-04-06_03-10-12.tar
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  214702080 Apr  7 03:10 admin.2020-04-07_03-10-13.tar
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  214732800 Apr  8 03:10 admin.2020-04-08_03-10-13.tar
```

I have tried running the command as backup user, but I get the same error, but when reading the individual files (since they are own by admin) This is a vestaCP setup, in case anyone has figured a different solution.
I have tried using the remote sftp setup, but i have had no luck, plus with Rsync I can use ssh keys.

I think the issue is because the folder is owned by backup user and files are owned by admin user. 
I am still a beginner to ubuntu and centos. 
I am trying to leave the permissions untouched, since I would run this command from Cron every morning right after the VestaCP Backup.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your admin user doesn't have permission to list the contents of the `/home/backup` directory.

Relax the permissions. For example, if your admin user is a member of the group `admin` you could consider this

```
chgrp admin /home/backup
chmod g=rx /home/backup
```

Comment: would this add the user admin to the group backup to give access to list the backup folder?

Comment: No. `man chgrp` and `man chmod` will show you that the first command changes the group of the `/home/backup` directory, and the second command relaxes the permissions for the group